# Add/Remove parent div to another div by clicking button

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'd like the parent div ".card" of the button to be added to the blue div upon clicking the button, and also able to "returned" to the original red div upon clicking the button again.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8n1b8z1/)

```
<div id="nonSelected">

  <div class="card">
   CARD #1
   <input id="btnDefault" onclick="moveButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="ADD" />
  </div>

  <div class="card">
   CARD #2
   <input id="btnDefault" onclick="moveButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="ADD" />
  </div>

</div>

<div id="selected">
</div>


<script>
function moveButton(elem){
    if( $(elem).parent().attr("id") == "nonSelected" ){
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('#selected');
    }
    else{
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('#nonSelected'); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `id` attributes *must* be unique within a document, so you should remove the `id` properties from the `input` elements within `.card` (or make them unique). Secondly your fiddle example did not include jQuery.

To fix your actual issue you can retrieve the parent `.card` from the `input` using `closest()`. You can then `append()` this to the required `div` by checking which one it is currently contained in, something like this:

```
$('.card input').click(function() {
    var $card = $(this).closest('.card')
    $card.appendTo($card.closest('#nonSelected').length ? '#selected' : '#nonSelected');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o8n1b8z1/2/)

Note that you don't need to call `detach()` at all as the element is simply moved within the DOM. Also note that it's much better practice to use unobtrusive javascript to attach your event handlers instead of the clunky and outdated `on*` event attributes. As you had already included jQuery code, I used that to achieve this.